# Create a two-dimensional structure containing data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I want to create a two-dimensional structure containing data frames (without using for loops).

I tried this, where `loadDF` returns a data.frame.

```
langs <- c("en_US", "de_DE", "fi_FI", "ru_RU")
types <- c("blogs", "news", "twitter")
tables <- 
    sapply(langs, function(lang) sapply(types, function(type) loadDF(lang, type)))
```

I hope then to be able to index into `tables` using something like

```
tables["de_DE", "twitter"]
```

or maybe something like this:

```
tables[which(langs == "de_DE"), which(types == "twitter")]
```

getting a data frame.

How do you do create such a structure?  Or is that not possible in R?  If it's not possible, what is the best alternative?

Comment: Short answer: You don't.  The R `list` type is all you got, and is 'linear' or 'sequential'.  Longer answer:   You can play with the different OO programming approaches to mock something.

Comment: it is not clear to me what you want to achieve furthermore `loadDF` to which package belongs to?

Comment: loadDF does not belong to any package.  It returns a data.frame.  That's the only thing that matters as far as this problem goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here i've created a `loadDF` function to make this example reproducible

```
loadDF<-function(a,b) {
    data.frame(a=a, b=b, x=runif(3))
}
```

If you stuff your items into a list, you can actually get a structure similar to what you want

```
tables <- 
    sapply(langs, function(lang) sapply(types, function(type) list(loadDF(lang, type))))
```

Then you can do

```
tables[["twitter","de_DE"]]
```

note that we use double brackets here to extract the data.frame from this dimensioned list.

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I wanted!